# Z-Indexed container isn't clickable

Tags: html, css, z-index

I've implemented a bootstrap snippet for video header on my website. It consists of 3 layers:
1. Video (z-index: 0)
2. Overlay of the video (z-index: 1)
3. Text and button (z-index:3)

The arrangement of layers work perfectly, with video being in the background, overlay on top of it, and then text and button on all of that. However, the text and button on front layer isn't clickable, so the button is not in function.

```css
header {
  position: relative;
  background-color: transparent;
  height: 75vh;
  min-height: 25rem;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

header video {
  position: absolute;
 z-index: 0;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

header .container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

header .overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #37250F;
  opacity: 0.5;
 z-index: 1;
}

@media (pointer: coarse) and (hover: none) {
  header {
    background: url('https://source.unsplash.com/XT5OInaElMw/1600x900') black no-repeat center center scroll;
  }
  header video {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <video playsinline="playsinline" autoplay="autoplay" muted="muted" loop="loop">
    <source src="https://storage.googleapis.com/coverr-main/mp4/Mt_Baker.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
  <div class="container h-100">
    <div class="d-flex h-100 text-center align-items-center">
      <div class="w-100 text-white">
        <h1 style="font-size:250%; text-align: center; padding-top:170px;">Preplati se na dostavu svježeg voća</h1>
       <form action="http://www.opgnjavro.hr/dostava-voca/">
       <button class="snip1562">Saznaj više</button>
       </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: What do you mean *isn't clickable*  - does it not receive the click event, or does simply not happen what you expect when you click it?

Comment: Include your javascript code

Comment: Assuming that the button actually works (have you tried it without the layering?) the button is buried in 3 divs, 1 form, and the overlay itself so unwrap the button from all of that garbage and make it a sibling of overlay not a great to the 4th grand niece

Answer (score 0):

It's been fixed. I was mixing Elementor with WordPress theme and the navigation of WP theme blocked the Elementor HTML code.

Thanks everyone!